# PHP display alternate page if condition is true

Tags: php

I am using the following code to display a 404 page if the user requests a URL which doesn't match an article in the database:

```
if($articleTitle == "")
{
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    readfile('404.php');
    exit();
}
```

`readfile` properly displays a webpage, but it does not parse PHP code in it. Is there an alternative to `readfile` that displays a different file but parses PHP in that other file? Since this is a 404, a redirect would be bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readfile` only slurps in raw bytes and spits them out to the client. You want `include()`, which WILL try to execute any PHP found in the loaded file.

Comment: But will that overwrite the rest of the page which calls the `include`?

Comment: not sure what you mean. but since your code has an exit() after the readfile, it doesn't matter what's in the rest of the script with tha tcode - it'll exit after readfile/include are done anyways.

Comment: I just tested it and that works. Yes, the `exit();` seems to be what prevents two pages from displaying ontop of each other.